# Fazaail of "GHUSAL"

Tags: practical-islam, ghusl

What is the "fazeelat" of "Ghusal". 
How to perform it's "fraiz"? 
What to do if a person don't know the is "farz" on him/her?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you define fazila (fadilah)? Fadilah in Arabic means "rest" it may also refer to something that goes beyond the necessary which we usually call sunnah or nafl. Therefore I think this is covered -for the hanafi madhhab- in [Ghusl janabat or ghusl to remove impurties](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27924/ghusl-janabat-or-ghusl-to-remove-impurities?) which makes this post a duplicate. Faraid of ghusl of all 4 sunni schools are addressed in [How to perform mandatory ghusl while fasting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/how-to-perform-mandatory-ghusal-while-fasting)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are three fards of ghusl:
1.Washing both the hands up to the wrists.
2.Wash the private parts and remove dirt or filth from the body.
3.Perform wudu.
4.Water should be poured over the head three times so that it flows all over the body.
5.Pour water on the right shoulder three times.
6.Pour water on the left shoulder three times.

https://hadithoftheday.com/ghusl-for-ladies/
also see this link

Comment: You say there are three Fards of ghusl and count 6 acts??? First this is a madhhab based view you didn't mention which madhhabs hold this opinion!

Comment: Brother i have given overall method of performing ghusal and just tell that how many Fard are in Ghusal.

Answer (score 2):

There are three fraiz of ghusl:
1. Gargling mouth with water
2. Clean nose by inhaling water
3. Pour water on the entire body such that no place is left dry. Even if its the size of an hair

Note that these are the mandatory thing which is to make sure while doing ghusl